# TYPO3 console - error when running cleanup:updatereferenceindex

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x, typo3-console

I get an error when running cleanup:updatereferenceindex:

> typo3cms cleanup:updatereferenceindex --verbose --show-progress
>   Record tt_content:2823 0 indexes were added and 1 stale indexes were removed.
>     80424/5208014 [>---------------------------]   1% 18 secs
>   Record static_countries:41 4 indexes were added and 4 stale indexes were removed.
>      81880/5208014 [>---------------------------]   1% 19 secsKilled
>
> ...
>   Updating reference index. This may take a while …
>     81883/5208017 [>---------------------------]   1% 57 secs
>   mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
>   Killed

What might causes this and how can I get it to run through and update the reference index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite clear:

> Cannot allocate memory Killed

means that the process was killed because PHP has not enough memory.
Fixing the issue could be done either by running the process several times or better by increasing the available memory for PHP in `php.ini` with the parameter `max_memory_limit`.
If you're unable to increase the memory for PHP you've always a problem. Even if you've a local copy of the installation (with less restrictive memory-settings) and could do indexing there to update the server-database with your local database, the system is hardly usable for working online with it.

If you can increase the memory for PHP everything will be fine, else you should increase the hosting-package or change the hosting-company.

Comment: if you usually dont need it you could use this in the terminal - the memory limit gets increased just temporary: php -d memory_limit=-1 vendor/bin/typo3cms cleanup:updatereferenceindex --verbose --show-progress